# update a single column with join lookups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `adjustments` with columns `adjustable_id | adjustable_type | order_id`

`order_id` is the target column to fill with values, this value should come from another table `line_items` which has a `order_id` column.
`adjustable_id (int) and _type (varchar)` references that table.

```
table: adjustments
id  | adjustable_id | adjustable_type | order_id
------------------------------------------------
100 | 1             | line_item       | NULL
101 | 2             | line_item       | NULL

table: line_items
id | order_id | other | columns
--------------------------------
1  | 10       | bla   | bla
2  | 20       | bla   | bla
```

In the case above I guess I need a join query to update `adjustments.order_id` first row with value `10`, second row with `20` and so on for the other rows using Postgres 9.3+.

In case the lookup fails, I need to delete invalid `adjustments` rows, for which they have no corresponding line_items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first one using a co-related sub-query:

```
update adjustments a
  set order_id = (select lorder_id 
                  from line_items l
                  where l.id = a.adjustable_id)
where a.adjustable_type = 'line_item';
```

this is standard ANSI SQL as standard SQL does not define a join condition for the `UPDATE` statement.

The second way is using a join, which is a Postgres extension to the SQL standard (other DBMS also support that but with different semantics and syntax).

```
update adjustments a
  set order_id = l.order_id 
from line_items l
where l.id = a.adjustable_id
  and a.adjustable_type = 'line_item';
```

The join is probably the faster one. Note that both versions (especially the first one) will **only** work if the join between line_items and adjustments will always return exactly one row from the line_items table. If that is not the case they will fail.

The reason why Arockia's query was "eating your RAM" is that his/her query creates a cross-join between table1 and table1 which is then joined against table2.

The Postgres manual [contains a warning about that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

> *Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*

Answer (score -1):

update a set A.name=B.name from table1 A join table2 B on 
A.id=B.id

Comment: this query let postgres fly at 100% cpu and eats all ram available on the system, care to rewrite the query for the example above? thanks.

Comment: [quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html): "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*"